# How might I use jQuery to show the first 8 elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a list of items (`<li>`), something like 50 of them, and I want to show only the first 8 items... How can I do that?

Comment: Are the list items hidden to start out with or are they visible?

Comment: u can also take a look at jQuery slice()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the less-than selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt) to select all list items with indexes less than 8 (index 8 is the ninth list item). Then show them:

```
$("#mylist li:lt(8)").show();
```

(assumes your list - `ol` or `ul` - has an `id` of `mylist`; adjust accordingly)

You might need to do this in two steps, if some list items are initially visible:

```
$("#mylist li") // select all list items
  .hide() // hide them
  .filter("li:lt(8)") // now select just the first eight
  .show(); // ...and show them.
```

(actually, this is over-kill unless some items are shown and some are hidden - if you know for a fact that all items are initially visible, you can use [the greater-than selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt) to simply hide items with index 8 and above - [as Corey demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811114/how-might-i-use-jquery-to-show-the-first-8-elements/1811139#1811139))

Answer (score 3):

```
$("li:lt(8)").show();
```

This selects the first 8 li elements.  The :li selects elements with an index less than the chosen number.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li:gt(7)').hide();
```

You use 7 because it's a zero based index.

Answer (score 2):

$("li:lt(8)") the :lt selects all li elements with index less than 8